# jQuery - получить data-item значение у текущей ссылки из множества ссылок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Код работает но alert() вызывается только по клику первой ссылки. Остальные ссылки не хотят выводить то что хранится в data-item. Ссылок много на странице, id у них одинаковый. В data-item попадает id из базы.

```
<a id="delete" data-item="<?= $model->id ?>">Удалить</a>



$('#delete').click( function () {

var id = $(this).attr('data-item');

alert(id);
});
```

Comment: >id у них одинаковый, конечно не будет работать, в DOM не может быть больше одного элемента с одним и тем же id !! поставьте или class name или просто по клику по ссылке получайте data-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарий от Arsen:

```
<a class="delete" href="#" data-item="<?= $model->id ?>">Удалить</a>
$('.delete').click( function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-item');
  alert(id);
});
```

Также не забудьте о атрибуте href. Он обязателен к ссылкам. Или замените ее на button

Comment: В данном случае ссылка работает через ajax поэтому href не обязателен. Вписал в атрибут href="javascript:void(null)" для отключения обновления страницы.

Answer (score 0):

вот в одну строчку на **vanilla**.
Но как правильные люди говорят `id` должен быть на странице один это так на будущее.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.id === 'my' &&
  console.log(event.target.dataset.item) // тут ваша логика
},true)
```

```html
<a class="delete" id="my" href="#" data-item="1">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" id="my" href="#" data-item="2">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" id="my" href="#" data-item="3">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" id="my" href="#" data-item="4">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" href="#" data-item="5">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" href="#" data-item="<6">Удалить</a><br>
<a class="delete" href="#" data-item="<7">Удалить</a><br>
```

Comment: супер и оригинально